# Upload file chunks sequentially using forkjoin and wait for response before firing next api call

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have the following piece of code, basically i am trying to upload chunks of a large file to signed urls returned from a service..

I need to call the uploadcompleted endpoint only after all the PUT requests in the returned forkjoin have been completed, but the issue i am facing is that I am not able to wait for the chunks to be uploaded to the signed url.

What am i doing wrong here? Any help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
filechunks(chunk: any, uploadUrls: string[], index) {
    let observableBatch = [];

    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    });
    observableBatch.push(this._http.put<any>(uploadUrls[index], chunk, { headers }))
    return forkJoin(observableBatch).pipe(delay(1000));
    // const createRequest = () => of(this._http.put<any>(uploadUrls[index], chunk, { headers }));
    // return forkJoin(createRequest).pipe(delay(1000));
  }

uploadfileinchunks(uniqueFileId: string, uploadId: string, chunks, uploadUrls): Observable<any> {
    let response = [];

    chunks.map( (chunk, i) => {
      let response = this.filechunks(chunk, uploadUrls, i).toPromise();
      console.log(response) 
    });


    const params = {
      some-id: some-id
    };

    return this._http.post<FileData>(
      `${somurl}/uploadcompleted`,
      {},
      {  {}, params }
    );
  }
```

Comment: this.filechunks(chunk, uploadUrls, i).toPromise(); this will get executed asynchronously and uploadfilechunks will run post immediately without waiting

Answer (score 0):

#### Interpretation:

Your code doesn't really make sense, so it's hard to figure out what you're even trying to do

```js
filechunks(chunk: any, uploadUrls: string[], index) {
  const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  });

  // observableBatch is an array of size 1. Why bother?
  const observableBatch = [];  
  observableBatch.push(
    this._http.put<any>(
      uploadUrls[index], 
      chunk, 
      { headers }
    )
  );

  // You're runnung forkJoin on a single observable? Again, why?
  return forkJoin(observableBatch).pipe(delay(1000));
}

uploadfileinchunks(uniqueFileId: string, uploadId: string, chunks, uploadUrls): Observable<any> {
  
  // Here, response is declared, but it's never used. You can delete this.
  let response = [];

  // chunks#map is a mapping function, but you're mapping every element to
  // null. Maybe what you mean is forEach?
  chunks.map( (chunk, i) => {
    // This a new response, this one is a promise. If you want the result
    // returned from filechunks, you'd need to resolve this promise
    // with response.then(LAMBDA) or await response
    // Also, mixing observables and promises is often a code smell.
    let response = this.filechunks(chunk, uploadUrls, i).toPromise();
    // You're logging a promise object here, not its resolved value
    console.log(response) 
  });

  // Not sure what this is?
  const params = {
    some-id: some-id
  };

  // call the uploadcompleted endpoint, but you haven't waited 
  // for your other calls to complete. That's what this question is about.
  return this._http.post<FileData>(
    `${somurl}/uploadcompleted`,
    {},
    {  {}, params }
  );
}
```

#### My best guess at what you meant to do:

I obviously can't test this and it's incomplete anyway as your question is pretty vague, but maybe this will lead you down the right path?

Remember that `uploadfileinchunks` returns an Observable and observables don't do anything until you `subscribe`. So wherever this code is called, you'll need to be sure to do that.

```js
filechunks(chunk: any, uploadUrls: string[], index) {
  return this._http.put<any>(
    uploadUrls[index], 
    chunk, 
    { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      })
    }
  ).pipe(
    delay(1000)
  );
}

uploadfileinchunks(uniqueFileId: string, uploadId: string, chunks, uploadUrls): Observable<any> {

  return forkJoin(chunks.map(
    (chunk, i) => this.filechunks(chunk, uploadUrls, i)
  ).pipe(
    map(response => ({
      some-id: "some-id"
    })),
    switchMap(params => this._http.post<FileData>(
      `${somurl}/uploadcompleted`,
      {},
      {  {}, params }
    ))
  );
}
```